# Azure Functions - some public and some protected?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Functions with my app, most functions needs to be protected by the authentication scheme I've set up however some functions need to be accessible anonymously.

What I'd like to accomplish with this design is to have my app pass in a refresh_token to the azure function which contains the client secret to refresh the token for the user without the end device ever needing to know about the secret key.

Another option I can do is have a separate azure project with some publicly accessible functions.

Comment: So what's the problem? You set `authLevel` for each function separately.

Comment: Perhaps I don't know how authLevel works but once I added Authentication to the azure functions all the functions became protected requiring an access token be passed in and all the functions are also anonymous...

Comment: Dude no. Easy Auth, the portal feature is a completely separate thing to authLevel. Just read up on the latter, it's all you need, you don't have to bring in Oauth.

Comment: It seems that you are using the user-based authentication ([Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)) for you function app. As Mikhail commented that you could set Authorization level for each functions, while the Easy Auth you configured is for the whole function app.

Comment: AFAIK, the Easy Auth would be authenticated before the function level authentication, and if you both enable user-based function app authentication and the function level authentication, then they would both be authenticated. For your scenario, you could set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** option to **Allow Anonymous requests (no action)**, then you need to validate the authentication in your each function if they need to be authenticated before accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options when doing Auth in Azure Functions:

1. Use API Keys via the `code` query/header (authLevel setting in function.json in front of individual Functions.
2. Use "Easy Auth" which can put AAD in front of all your Functions
3. Do it yourself

I'd recommend just using a jwt library or something similar to do it yourself if you're doing something fancy.

I also recommend not having unauthenticated and authenticated Functions on the same Function App, just create two different Apps. This makes it harder to accidentally have escalation of privilege issues pop up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, I think I agree with you - another function app with a simple RefreshToken function will probably save a lot of pain in the long run...